# Schizoaffective disorder and bipolar disorder, how to make the right diagnosis?

Tags: schizophrenia, mood, bipolar-disorder, diagnosis

How not to confuse a schizoaffective disorder and a bipolar disorder in the manic phase where the person experiences pseudo-hallucinations? In both cases, there are mood symptoms and schizophrenia. What are the elements that can tip the scales to make the right diagnosis?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. To me, a quick Google search on the definition of *Schizoaffective Disorder* gives you an answer from a reputable source. What have you read on the subject and what (if anything) makes you confused or unsure of the facts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993).